# Is it possible to use transparent PNG in ME tile and lockscreen?

Tags: file-format

I tried more than once use a png file in ME tile with the back ground transparent but looks like the phone made a mess with the file.

Someone know how to do this? What is the specification of a png to works with transparency in Windows Phone.

P.S. In the browser it works but as soon as I download the file it looses the transparency.

Picture in computer

[image: Picure in computer]

Picture in the phone

[image: Picture in the phone]

Comment: How are you downloading / transferring the file? Have you tried sending it over using the USB cable?

Comment: I tried download from browser and SkyDrive. Never tried from Zune. I will try.

Comment: @TomWijsman Just tried with Zune. It does not recognizes png files. It shows only jpg files.

Answer (score 4):

**Me** will most likely not work because it only takes JPG files as you seem to suggest, as for downloading from online sources it might either be unsupported or it doesn't work due to compression.

As for the **lock screen**, it has [been tried before](http://gathering.tweakers.net/forum/list_message/36942760#36942760) but it doesn't really look well due to bad redraws:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've just find [this way](http://phone7.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/creating-transparent-lockscreen-wallpapers-for-wp7/) and has the same problem you showed.

Comment: I don't know what the person in that thread did, but I believe he probably had some corrupted PNG files or at least an incompatible PNG format (though I don't know if there are any). Transparent lockscreens are doable. I've used them before. But they only work if you don't lock the phone with a PIN.

Comment: @sidran32: No, it's fully compatible and not corrupted; Vitor has tested it as well and confirmed that. The thing here is that the sliding action is broken, which makes transparent lock screens very unfeasible. Unless you want to run around with an insecure phone where you only see it while you unlock it (in comparison with nasty effects that stay visible on the screen until it's unlocked)...

Comment: @TomWijsman I swear that I didn't see this when I used them. It has been a while, though. I'll probably try them out again since I'm now curious. Maybe if it is a universal problem, it could have been something broken with a recent OS update.

Comment: Ah, tried it myself and I see the same thing. I believe that before Mango, it would just show black instead of corrupted imagery. It appears that it probably just shows whatever garbage was in memory. (Here's an [old post](http://phone7.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/creating-transparent-lockscreen-wallpapers-for-wp7/) that I tested with that demonstrates the old behavior).

Comment: Yeah, that's what Vitor linked; but the behavior appeared to have changed.